# Angular2 Quickstart cannot start with lite-server

Tags: node.js, windows, typescript, angular, lite-server

I have been trying to get the Angular2 Quick start app working on Windows system, but could not succeed with the "lite-server".

After installing dependencies(npm install) when i run the app(npm start) i get the following error

```
> Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
[1]     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1007:11)
[1]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32                                     )
[1]     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
[1]     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
[1]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
[1]
[1] npm
[1]  ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
[1] npm ERR! argv "D:\\Softwares\\node6\\node.exe" "D:\\Softwares\\node6\\node_m                                     odules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "lite"
[1] npm ERR! node v6.2.2
[1] npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
[1] npm ERR! code
[1]  ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! angular2-starter@0.9.0 lite: `lite-server`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR!
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-starter@0.9.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
[1] npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
[1] npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-starter                                      package,
[1] npm ERR! not with npm itself.
[1] npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
[1] npm ERR!     lite-server
[1] npm
[1]  ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
[1] npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-starter
[1] npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
[1] npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-starter
[1] npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
[1]
[1] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[1] npm ERR!     D:\Dev\Angular2-JumpStart\npm-debug.log
[1] npm run lite exited with code 1
```

As you see above my node(v6.2.2) and npm(v3.9.5). I have also tried with older node versions, but no luck. I have also installed the lite-server globally(just for information).

I have followed and tried some of the suggestions online but none of them work.

strangely this problem does not persist on my Mac machine.

I appreciate your support :)

Comment: Recheck your package.json- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files

Answer (score 1):

I have this same exact problem, same version numbers and everything. Adding "C:\Windows\System32\" to system PATH variable fixed the problem. I had been trying to figure out for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it by myself. I have to update my Path variables with "C:\Windows\System32\".

The problem lies in the error message `> Error: spawn cmd ENOENT`